# Как разделить один div на 4 одинаковые части?

Tags: html, css, разметка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как разделить один div на 4 одинаковые части?

Comment: что значит _разделить_?

Comment: Блок разделить на 4 части?Вам нужно в четырех  блоках  `div` поставить  `width` 25%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}

.wrapper-inner {
  position: relative;
  align-self: stretch;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.wrapper-inner:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(55, 71, 79, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper-inner._bg-0 {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/iLYwNUt.jpg);
}

.wrapper-inner._bg-1 {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Hk0pCIG.jpg);
}

.wrapper-inner._bg-2 {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/hYsr8VD.jpg);
}

.wrapper-inner._bg-3 {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/7ovysYf.jpg);
}

.wrapper-inner-title {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.wrapper-inner-subtext {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  padding: 16px;
  bottom: 62px;
  left: -62px;
  letter-spacing: 0.4em;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper-inner _bg-0">
    <div class="wrapper-inner-title">Modern living room</div>
    <div class="wrapper-inner-subtext">Interior design</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-inner _bg-1">
    <div class="wrapper-inner-title">Modern living room</div>
    <div class="wrapper-inner-subtext">Interior design</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-inner _bg-2">
    <div class="wrapper-inner-title">Modern living room</div>
    <div class="wrapper-inner-subtext">Interior design</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-inner _bg-3">
    <div class="wrapper-inner-title">Modern living room</div>
    <div class="wrapper-inner-subtext">Interior design</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: @LEV не за что.

Answer (score 4):

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.items{     
  overflow: hidden;  
  font-size: 0;  
}
.item{  
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 100vh;  
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;  
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}
.item:nth-of-type(even){
  background: #ddd;
}
.item:after{
  content: 'text design';
  position: absolute; bottom: 5%; left: 5%;
  text-transform: uppercase;  
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;  
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

В любом случае придется в div добавить еще четыре других div'а. И потом применить флекс.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex > div {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Например делим на 2 колонки

```css
.div1 {
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 150px;
  background: #ccc;
  float: left;
}

.div2 {
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 150px;
  background: #c00;
  margin-left: 70%;
}

.footer {
  clear: left;
  background: #000;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">div1</div>
<div class="div2">div2</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

<sub>[jsfiddle-dn5r3](http://jsfiddle.net/dn5r3/)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум - ложим в один `div` ещё четыре `div class="inner-block"`, а потом что-то вроде

```
.inner-block {
width: 25%;
float:left;
// Ещё стили
}
```

А вообще, попробуйте ознакомиться с замечательным фреймворком [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). Он достаточно лёгкий в понимании, и с ним вы сможете избежать лишней писанины в стилях(медиа запросы для адаптивности, размеры блоков).